# Sending AJAX to PHP not displaying

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getchoices.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "userName": "test1", "password" : "test2" })
});
```

With corresponding PHP:

```
<?php
    $json = $_POST;
    print_r($json);
?>
```

However my output for `getchoices.php` is just `Array ( )`

I have implemented the solution below, with the correct output from the console, however the PHP is not displaying anything.

Comment: `print_r($json)` will be rejected by jQuery: the dataType applies to _the expected response format_ `print_r` is not valid JSON, use `echo json_encode($array);` instead and don't use the closing tag. And as ever: _don't stringify data yourself: jQ will serialize your data and send it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 6):

No need to stringify the data.Just try like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getchoices.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "userName": "test1", "password" : "test2" }
    });
```

And in getchoices.php

```
//$_POST['userName'] = test1;
//$_POST['password'] = test2;

$json = $_POST;
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: I just copied this exactly and getting an empty array in getchoices.php

Comment: I have no errors in the console, and in the 'preview' for getchoices.php it works perfectly, however the page itself does not

Answer (score 0):

use this php function `json_encode`

```
$test = array('foo' => 'bar'); 
echo json_encode($test);
```